# Parse.com facebook login with asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform, webbrowser-control, facebook-login

I'm trying to setup the Parse.com login to website using Facebook, and i didn't understand how. I couldn't find any examples of code in the internet.. as wrote in parse documentation:

```
// Make your browser control visible
   try
   {
       ParseUser user = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(
                        browser, new[] { "user_likes", "email" });
       // The user logged in with Facebook!
   }
   catch
   {
       // User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.
    }
    // Hide your browser control
```

I don't know how to Make the browser control visible && how to hide it when the login process is finished. I'll be happy to get help. Thanks!

Comment: you do know that parse will be gone in less than a year, right? just saying. i would not build something new on it, unless you use it on your own server.

Comment: Can you explain me more? Recently I used open source version of Parse and create my server and solution